# What are these processes come from?

Tags: 16.04

Linux ubuntu-srv16 4.4.0-206-generic #238-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 16 07:51:47 UTC 2021 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
I noticed something and I can't figure out what it is.

Also "distort -root", "ripples -root" and other names came in the past

[image: I can't figure out]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tesselimage

Is part of a screensaver program. Probably `gnome-screensaver` and if not likely `xscreensaver`.

> [shadebobs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shadebobs)

Is something to do with "oscilating vapor trails" so I assume is part of tesselimage.

Comment: Some details needed about tesselimage, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=tesselimage . The shadebobs is ok, as per https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=shadebobs&searchon=contents .